# comparing four dictionaries that their keys are same but each has different values in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-3.7

i have four dictionaries like below and i want to print them in order of their first values and if they were equal then print them in order of their second values but i cant figure a way. i've tried to put all of the values of 'p' in a list and sort the list but again i couldn't find a way to call which value is for which dictionary

```
a = {'p':10, 'w':3}
b = {'p':2, 'w':0}
c = {'p':3, 'w':0}
d = {'p':3, 'w':1}
```

the output should be this:

```
{'p':10, 'w':3}
{'p':3, 'w':1}
{'p':3, 'w':0}
{'p':2, 'w':0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to `sorted` to get the custom sort order.

```
a = {'p':10, 'w':3}
b = {'p':2, 'w':0}
c = {'p':3, 'w':0}
d = {'p':3, 'w':1}

dicts = [a,b,c,d]

print(sorted(dicts, reverse=True, key=lambda d: (d['p'], d['w'])))
```

For each dict, the `key` is the tuple of the `p` value and the `w` value - which gives the required sort order

Output:

```
[{'p': 10, 'w': 3}, {'p': 3, 'w': 1}, {'p': 3, 'w': 0}, {'p': 2, 'w': 0}]
```

Comment: You could also use `operator.itemgetter('p', 'w')` in place of the lambda ,e.g. `import operator as op; sorted(dicts, reverse=True, key=op.itemgetter('p', 'w'))`

Answer (score 1):

Use the key argument of the sort function. Here is a solution to the problem (note that reverse makes sure the largest appears first).

```
dict_list = [a,b,c,d]
dict_list.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: (x['p'], x['w']))
print(dict_list)
[{'p': 10, 'w': 3}, {'p': 3, 'w': 1}, {'p': 3, 'w': 0}, {'p': 2, 'w': 0}]
```